# Tomcat graceful shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, shutdown

I am using Tomcat 8.x.x and  starting the tomcat using startup.sh. I verified that tomcat is up and running using JPS command. I am stopping the Tomcat using **catalina.sh stop 100**. As per catalina shell scripts says it will wait for 100 seconds to terminate the tomcat process. But tomcat process terminated immediately, verified by JPS command.

Why Graceful shutdown is not working ?

How to achieve the Graceful shutdown in Tomcat ?

Answer (score 10):

The 100 seconds is how long the script will wait for the process to stop after issuing the kill signal before terminating it more forcefully with `kill -9`. Just because the process stops quickly, doesn't mean it wasn't a clean shutdown.

From the catalina.sh help section:

```
echo "  stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end"
echo "  stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end"
echo "  stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
echo "  stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running"
```

Notice the verbiage *waiting up to n seconds* ... the process is signaled right away, and the script waits up to *n* seconds for the PID to disappear before it sends the `kill -9` signal. Note that the catalina.sh script does sleep for 1 second at a time, but only after it has sent the initial shutdown signal.

Here are the relevant lines from the script that show you exactly what's happening:

https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/a8c62dd061d4cf937c3bdec615121696916434eb/bin/catalina.sh#L525-L600

In general:

- Send a `kill -15` to the process, which is a normal, graceful shutdown. It is now up to the JVM to start its termination sequence.
- Send a `kill -0` to the process to check if it is alive or not. If it's alive, sleep for 1 second and check again. Repeat this until either a) the process is no longer alive, or b) the delay parameter (in your case, 100 seconds) has elapsed.
- If the process is **still** alive at this point, and you have provided the `-force` argument, the script tries one last time to send a `kill -9` signal to the JVM. This signal cannot actually be handled by the JVM, and the OS itself forces an immediate shutdown of the process (i.e. a not graceful shutdown).

Notice all of this happened right away, without any delay. If you want to have some artificial pause before attempting the shutdown sequence above, you should use `sleep` before calling catalina.sh:

```
sleep 100 && catalina.sh stop
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am not seeing any delay in script execution or tomcat termination. Script executed immediately and tomcat terminated immediately . Please try and let me know.

Comment: Correct, that is by design. The _n_ parameter is *not* a delay in stopping the process, it's how long to wait for the process to stop. If you want a delay before shutdown, you need to use a _sleep_ or other command before calling catalina.sh.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. graceful shutdown means it will give delay before terminate the process. Here my tomcat process is terminated immediately. I verified using JPS command. Where I am seeing delay ? in script ( no ) , in tomcat ( no ) , process id ( no ). please give more detail to understand the graceful shutdown in tomcat

Comment: Your understanding of graceful shutdown is not accurate. It simply means giving the process a chance to terminate normally (i.e. using a regular `kill` command with default `TERM` signal). The JVM can catch this signal and perform regular shutdown. The command is sent immediately from catalina.sh without delay. The _n_ parameter is how long the script will keep checking for the process to end. After _n_ seconds, if the PID is still running and you have also provided `-force`, catalina.sh will use `kill -9`. This signal cannot be handled by any process, and the OS immediately stops the process.

Comment: My expectation of graceful shutdown means stop accepting new request from client and wait for 30 seconds to complete the already received ( in-progress) request.  so that we won't lose any request. But I don't think tomcat does this. script ensure that process is terminated or not in specified time ( n ). this is not helpful and this is not graceful shutdown

Comment: By using `kill -15` first, the JVM should have a chance to stop accepting requests and finish in flight requests before terminating. If it's not, you might consider enabling the shutdown port and seeing if that works better: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/server.html