# Increase Tomcat shutdown timeout

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, tomcat9

I need to increase Tomcat shutdown timeout to 45 seconds in Windows. When I stop Tomcat in the services. It takes almost 35-40 seconds. How could I increase shutdown timeout in Tomcat configuration?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars1808/increasing-the-shutdown-timeout-in-the-tomcat-configuration-tool-820495877.html or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878053/tomcat-graceful-shutdown

Comment: I didn't understand first link. Where is this Start > All Programs > Apache Tomcat > Configure Tomcat path ? The other link is not clear to put the time where. Could you help me little to clarify?

Comment: How are you initiating the shutdown?

Comment: Well, the second link states that you'd pass the shutdown timeout to `catalina.sh` (on Windows it's probably `catalina.bat`) so you might look into those scripts which normally can be found in Tomcat's bin directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According for the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html) for the Windows services integration, there is a `--StopTimeout` option that you can provide when configuring the service that gives a timeout for graceful service shutdowns.

If you have already installed the service, you can edit the `StopTimeout` value via the "Shutdown" tab of the Tomcat Monitor.

Note that this parameter is a standard `procrun` setting.

Comment: This value can also be edited in the _"Shutdown"_ tab of Tomcat Monitor (procrun).

Comment: Should I add at service.bat like "--StopTimeout="45" ?

Comment: `service.bat` is only used when you install a new service. Run `tomcat9.exe //US --StopTimeout=45` or change the value in the graphical interface _"Tomcat Monitor"_ (the `tomcat9w.exe` executable).

Comment: I added StopTimeout=45 in service.bat as a parameter. Then I installed. I saw 45 seconds timeout in the shutdown tab. But how could I test it?

Comment: Try shutting down Tomcat and see if it shuts down cleanly (rather than being killed).  For extra points, set the value to (say) 10 seconds and observe what happens when Tomcat shutdown takes too long.  Check the logs.

Comment: @StephenC I did 1 second and it takes more than 1 second. And I couldn't any log where it is ? There is no log  Tomcat/logs directory. Just Installation logs exists.

Comment: Increase Tomcat Monitor logging to `DEBUG` and check `commons-daemon.<date>.log`.

Comment: @GccGUY - What you are looking for is indications in the logs that Tomcat has been >>killed<< during shutdown.

Comment: Yeah I am looking like that. But I couldn't get any log. When I changed the DEBUG or checked  in the logs/ folder.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but maybe anything helpful in workers.properties file in ../httpd/conf/

Comment: I couldn't find workers.properties in Tomcat or C:/ . Could you type certain path?

Comment: It depends on your OS, see https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc-archive/jk2/jk/quickhowto.html

Comment: Yeah, it explains for Linux distribution. But i execute Tomcat in Windows.

Comment: If you want answers that are specific to Windows, you should mention that in the question.

Comment: Yes, I added now.